# Android pie non sdk interface issue

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have updated one of my application to api 28(android pie). and also tested in firebase robo device api 28 and got result pass but getting these warning "Your app uses 12 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+". i have checked all of them are in light-grey list. But in google console pre-launch report i am getting error. can't figure out how to solve this.[ image of firebase warning report is here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGLtK.jpg

Comment: Try adding `detectNonSdkApiUsage` using Strict Mode in your application class. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder#detectNonSdkApiUsage()

Comment: if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectNonSdkApiUsage()
                        .penaltyLog()
                        .build());
            }
        }
i had set this code in application class..but getting same result ...works well in all places but getting error in pre-launch report. Moreover, strickmode doesn't warm may be because of my all api are in light-gret listed (as per firebase report)

Comment: @DixitPatel Given the non-SDK interface errors, did Google Play Console let you publish the app or it is mandatory to solve them first?